# fgets not able to read from pipe twice on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I have the following code that used to work on Ubuntu 18.04. Now, I compiled and run it in Ubuntu 20.04, and, for some reason, the code stop working.

The code is meant to read from a named pipe. To test it, I create the pipe with `mkfifo /tmp/pipe` and then I write into the pipe with `echo "message" >> /tmp/pipe`.

The first time the `fgets()` method is executed, the function returns the expected value from the pipe; but from the second invocation on, the method returns `NULL` and the code gets stuck on the loop even when I execute several echo commands.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

FILE* result_pipe_stream;

string read_result_from_pipe(){
    if (result_pipe_stream == NULL){
        printf("\n[BINDING-COMMONS] ERROR: Pipe is not set");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    
    std::stringstream oss;
    while (1) {
        char buf[BUFSIZ];
        if( fgets (buf, BUFSIZ, result_pipe_stream) != NULL ) {
            int buflen = strlen(buf);
            if (buflen >0){
                if (buf[buflen-1] == '\n'){
                        buf[buflen-1] = '\0';
                        oss << buf;
                        return oss.str();
                } else {
                    oss << buf;
                    // line was truncated. Read another block to complete line.
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    result_pipe_stream = fopen("/tmp/pipe" , "r");
    while (1){
        cout << read_result_from_pipe() << '\n';
    }
}
```

1. Why is the code not working anymore? I assume that some library has changed in the distribution and fgets is no longer able to read properly from the pipe
2. How can I workaround that problem?

Comment: You're combining `<string.h>` (not even `<cstring>`) with `<string>`, included by `<iostream>` and such. `using namespace std;` makes it worse. Don't do this. You're making problems. Next you're combining C with C++. Also don't do that. C++ has `fstream`s, which you should use.

Comment: this code will not be compiled ofc. so where is a real code?

Comment: I just compiled that code with g++ ¬¬u

Comment: "line was truncated" is not certainly true as the last line of the file/stream may lack a `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that was it. I just added a clearer(result_pipe_stream) and now I receive the message. Probably I should check the error and handle what to do in each case before clearing it. Thanks

Comment: @FrancescLordan BTW, if piped data includes a _null character_,, this reading approach needs re-work  to distinguish a _null character_ that was read from the appended one `fgets()` applies.  I'd consider `fread()` or more C++ like options.

Comment: True. However I am only transferring simple strings ( which may be very long) so that shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if( fgets (buf, BUFSIZ, result_pipe_stream) != NULL )` --> Once `fgets()` returns `NULL` due to end-of-file, it will continue to return `NULL` on subsequent calls *without reading*  unless the *end-of-file indicator* for `result_pipe_stream` is cleared - like with `clearerr()`.  Codes gets stuck in an infinite loop, never reading anymore and it *should*.

The real question is why it "worked" in Ubuntu 18.04. I suspect that version was not compliant.

```
while (1) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    if( fgets (buf, BUFSIZ, result_pipe_stream) != NULL ) {
      ...
    }
     // Perhaps assess why here, end-of-file, input error, too often here, ...
    clearerr(result_pipe_stream); // add
}
```

Comment: Francesc Lordan,  Perhaps a pipe on the older version, after setting _end-of-file indicator_ due to no data, cleared _end-of-file indicator_ when new data later arrived.  IMO, that would be non-compliant.  Once _end-of-file indicator_ is set, it should be cleared only under specified conditions.